# Testing grep output in bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm looking for a way to act differently in my `bash` script depending on my external IP address. To be more specific if my external IP address is `111.111.111.111` then do some action, otherwise do something else.

This is my code:

```
extIP=$(curl ifconfig.me | grep 111.111.111.111)

if [ -? ${extIP} ]
then
    runExecutable
else
    echo "111.111.111.111 is not your IP."
fi
```

I don't know how to test `extIP`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
echo 'Enter the IP Address you want to test'
read IP_ADDRESS
extIP=$(curl ifconfig.me | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')

if [ "$IP_ADDRESS" == "$extIP" ]
then
    bash runExecutable.sh
    exit 0
fi

echo '${IP_ADDRESS} is not your IP'
exit 1 # if it's bad or just exit 0 otherwise
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!  I'm also really trying to understand grep and sed too.  when you're running grep -o command what does the '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' mean and or doing?  Sorry for the new question

Comment: Hi, in general `grep` works with Regular Expressions. In fact, `grep` stands for [Global regular expression print](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abnd). The `-o` stands for _only matching_ which means that it shows *only* the part matched by the regular expression. `'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'`is a regular expression that captures numbers in format of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx like IP addresses. It could be optimized to just accept as a maximum of 4 digits, but assuming `ifconfig.me` only returns IP's then it's safe to use. You can learn more about regular expressions [here](https://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Just run the curl/grep command the check the exit status

```
curl ifconfig.me | grep -s 111.111.111.111
if [ "$?" == "0" ]
then 
    runExecutable
else
    echo "111.111.111.111 is not your IP."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test the exit code of your command pipeline [directly with `if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), like this:

```
addr="111.111.111.111"
if curl -s ifconfig.me | grep -qF "$addr"; then
    runExecutable "$addr" ...
else
    echo "$addr is not your IP."
fi
```

Also, you probably want to silence the `curl`'s progress output with `-s` and `grep`'s matches with `-q`, use a fixed string search in `grep` with `-F`, and store your IP address in a variable for easier later reuse.

Note the `[` is actually a shell command that exits with `0` if condition that follows is true, or with `1` otherwise. `if` than uses that exit code for branching.

See [this bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) for more details.

Comment: Conceptually the best answer here IMHO, but I think you need a space before the `;` and also, I would consider it a maintenance issue to repeat the same IP address twice and would prefer to see it replaced by a single variable that is set just once at the start. Good approach though +1.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Thank you, good point on variable/address reuse. I've edited my answer. Regarding the semicolon `;` -- there's no need for space before it, since `;` is a POSIX operator (like `|`, `&&`, or `&`), not keyword. To have been considered as a part of `grep` pattern it should have beed escaped.

Comment: I didn't know that, so thank you for putting me straight - it's good to learn!